# How to optimize ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular's ng-switch to build form's fields like this

```
<div ng-switch="vm.myField">
    <my-input-type1 ng-switch-when="type1"></my-input-type1>
    <my-input-type2 ng-switch-when="type2"></my-input-type2>
    <my-input-type3 ng-switch-when="type3"></my-input-type3>
    <my-input-type4 ng-switch-when="type4"></my-input-type4>
    <my-input-type5 ng-switch-when="type5"></my-input-type5>
    <my-input-type6 ng-switch-when="type6"></my-input-type6>
    <my-input-type7 ng-switch-when="type7"></my-input-type7>
    <my-input-type8 ng-switch-when="type8"></my-input-type8>
</div>
```

because of performance it's not good solution (on entering view with it brwser is pausing for a while).
Without `ng-switch` all is rather ok.

How can I optimize it? `ng-if` has the same prefomrance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution.
Insead of `ng-switch` I'm using
`<ng-include src="'/my-fields/directives/'+vm.myField+'.html'"></ng-include>` with proper html code.
For now works good but have to test a bit more.

EDIT: now it is much, much faster

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know from the Angular documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

ng-switch works by adding and removing the nested DOM element based on a conditional statement. This can be quite slow for large templates/DOM elements.

One solution I used was to use ng-show/ng-hide (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

These directives do not modify the DOM structure, but instead use CSS to hide/show the elements. It can be faster, but beware that the DOM could become very large if you fall into the trap of trying to contain all of templates/DOM elements of your web site in memory at the same time in this manner.

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.5's new component API and this is the faster option for switching between those. I miss routes still, but ui-router was quite poor for subviews using components.