# ng-switch-when does not have break statement?

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-switch and expecting that it will be a break statement after each condition. I tested with following with condtion gradeA and it display both Grade A-1 and Grade A-2. Am i missing some configuration? If not how to make ng-switch to contain break statement?

```
<div ng-switch="type">
    <div ng-switch-when="gradeA">
        Grade A-1   
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="gradeA">
        Grade A-2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `ng-switch-when` works like `ng-if`, which means if the condition satisfies, the block would be "shown" (technically it's *created* instead).

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch):

> `ngSwitchWhen`: the case statement to match against. If match then this case will be displayed. If the same match appears multiple times, all the elements will be displayed.

In your example, both cases are "case: gradeA", and thus both are shown.

If you wish to conditionally 'break out', use a nested `ng-if` or another nested `ng-switch`.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DtgLdLyq5N1iK1dBdQo9?p=preview)

In both `div`, you have used `ng-switch-when="gradeA"`. So code inside each `ng-switch-when` with matching value `GradeA` will be executed. That is why both `Grade A-1` and `Grade A-2` are displayed.

Your code should look like:

```
 <div ng-switch="type">
    <div ng-switch-when="gradeA-1">
        Grade A-1   
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="gradeA-2">
        Grade A-2
    </div>
 </div>
```

Notice that in above code, first `ng-switch-when` with matching value `gradeA-1` and second `ng-switch-when` with matching value `gradeA-2`. So there is no chance to be displayed both data.

Hope that solve your problem.

**Update:** [Performance Issue from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28880505/3186722)

> One solution I used was to use ng-show/ng-hide. These directives do
>   not modify the DOM structure, but instead use CSS to hide/show the
>   elements. It can be faster, but beware that the DOM could become very
>   large if you fall into the trap of trying to contain all of
>   templates/DOM elements of your web site in memory at the same time in
>   this manner.

[OP of that question also answered with a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28880650/3186722).

Comment: Hi my main concern is performance related issue when executed each of the login in ng-switch without break